# Test verifications on embedded Spring LDAP server

Tags: spring, testing, ldap

we are using the default embedded ldap server in spring for our integration tests and configured it as follows:

```
spring:
  ldap:
    embedded:
      base-dn: dc=XXX,dc=de
      ldif: classpath:eap-schema.ldif
      port: 34321
      validation:
        enabled: false
```

Everything works fine with that configuration in our tests.

We now implemented a caching of the user details provided by the ldap server after authentication. I would like to verify now that if we make to calls to our "userinfo" endpoint, the LDAP server is only called once by our application. I worked a lot with wiremock and i can get all events on a wiremock server pretty easy. I searched a lot but i could not find anything regarding this in the embedded ldap.

So has anyone an idea how i can verify that the ldap server was only called once in a @SpringBootTest integration test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can abstract the codes that interact with LDAP server to a separate class or interface (e.g. `LdapClient`) , you can easily use traditional mocking technique such as using Mockito to verify the codes that you want to test only call the `LdapClient` (i.e. LDAP Server) one time. You even do not need to use the "LDAP wiremock server".

So suppose the codes that you want to test is `getUserInfo()` in the following `UserService` class :

```java
public class UserService {
    
        private LdapClient ldapClient;
        private Map<String, User> userCache = new HashMap<>();

        private UserService(LdapClient ldapClinet) {
            this.ldapClient = ldapClinet;
        }

        public User getUserInfo(String uid) {

            if (userCache.containsKey(uid)) {
                return userCache.get(uid);
            } else {
                User user = ldapClient.getUser(uid);
                userCache.put(uid, user);
                return user;
            }
        }
}
```

And you want to verify if it will only call `LdapClient` one time even it is invoked for the same user multiple times. Then the test looks likes :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private LdapClient ldapClient;
    
    @Test
    public void testGetUserInfo() {

        UserService sut = new UserService(ldapClient);

        User u1 = sut.getUserInfo("foo");
        User u2 = sut.getUserInfo("foo");

        //verify ldapClient only call one time for the user "foo"
        verify(ldapClient, times(1)).getUser("foo");

        assertThat(u1).isEqualTo(u2);
    }

}
```

For the actual `LdapClient` implementation that interact to the real LDAP server , you need to have another test for it which test with the embedded LDAP server that you are using.

Both tests together should give you a pretty good test coverage for the things that you want to verify. I just give you the idea but it should be easily applied to your actual situation.